# VLCKit with AVPlayerLayer SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, avplayerlayer, vlckit

I am trying to use VLCKit along with AVPlayerLayer (in order to eventually use PIP)
I have VLCKit working correctly but I am unable to use it with PlayerLayer

This is the  most basic working example using AVPlayer as the player that I am trying to modify but with no luck. Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

class PlayerView: UIView {
    
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
    
    init(player: AVPlayer) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.player = player
        self.backgroundColor = .black
    }
        
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }
    
    // Override UIView property
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}

struct PlayerContainerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = PlayerView
    
    let player: AVPlayer
    
    init(player: AVPlayer) {
        self.player = player
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PlayerView {
        return PlayerView(player: player)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PlayerView, context: Context) { }
}

class PlayerViewModel: ObservableObject {

    let player: AVPlayer
    
    init(fileName: String) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "mp4")
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: url!))
    }
    
    @Published var isPlaying: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isPlaying {
                play()
            } else {
                pause()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func play() {
        let currentItem = player.currentItem
        if currentItem?.currentTime() == currentItem?.duration {
            currentItem?.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
        }
        
        player.play()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        player.pause()
    }
}

enum PlayerAction {
    case play
    case pause
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: PlayerViewModel
    init() {
        model = PlayerViewModel(fileName: "video")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
            
                PlayerContainerView(player: model.player)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.model.isPlaying.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: self.model.isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
                })
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: VLCKit does not support AVPlayerLayer as it is not based on AVPlayer. You cannot do PiP with VLCKit in the current release. You'll see a solution in the next major update some time this year.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you can't have classes in your `View` structs. So first rename `PlayerViewModel` as `PlayerCoordinator` and init it inside the `UIViewRepresentable`. It is also essential you implement `updateUIView` to copy the values from the struct to the objects, e.g. something like this:

```
class PlayerCoordinator {

    let player: AVPlayer
...

struct PlayerContainerView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        PlayerCoordinator()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PlayerView, context: Context) { 

        context.coordinator.didPlay = nil
        context.coordinator.didPause = nil

        if isPlaying == true && context.coordinator.player.isPlayer == false {
            context.coordinator.player.play()
        }

       if isPlaying == false && context.coordinator.player.isPlayer == true {

            context.coordinator.player.pause()
        }

        coordinator.didPause = {
            isPlaying = false
        }

        coordinator.didPlay = {
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then your View struct should be like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isPlaying = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
            
                PlayerView(isPlaying: isPlaying)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                
                Button(action: {
                    isPlaying.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
                })
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: My original code is actually working correctly, it's based off of this sample
https://github.com/popei69/samples/tree/master/videoSample.
I'm not sure where I have a class in my view struct ? The project wouldn't build in that case would it ?
I will try your modifications thanks, but will it help with transitioning to VLCKit ?

Comment: Sadly that sample isn’t code correctly, line 125 of ContentView is a memory leak